# vim: multiple conditions for different lines

Tags: vim

Is there any way to act on a line when serveral conditions matches only.
For exmaple, I have the text as

```
This is a blue coat
This is a red  coat
This is a purple coat
That is a coat
```

(PS: This text is borrowed from a nother similar question.)
If the current line matches `^This` and the following line matches `red`, and then do the normal command `A some text to be appended{Esc}`.

There is a simple way to achieve this like:

```
:%s/^This.*\ze\n.*red/&some text to be appended/e
```

However, when the conditions increase, the regex booms. Besides, this solution is not as elegant as I expected.
Is there anyway to be accomplished with `:gloabl` command?

After some answers given, I've found my question isn't clear enough, thus I append the following pseudo command to show what I'm seeking for.
The elegant way to achieve this for me is something like(but the following code won't work):

```
:g/^This\C/;.+1g/red/norm Asome text to be appended
```

The problem is, the first `:g` command won't pass lines but not block (I'm not sure if I'm correct), so it's unlikely to filter the biased condition (`red`, 1 line after).

If there exists a solution, thus I can easily handle the following actions:
Print "the line and three lines following" on condition that "the line contains `This` and 100 lines later contains `red`".

I hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: *"when the conditions increase, the regex booms"* That depends on what the conditions are... What do you have in mind? Your question would be better if you gave an example where using a regex would have been really impractical

Comment: *"Is there anyway to be accomplished with :global command?"* Yes. `:g/^This.*\n.*red/normal! Asome text to be appended` will append the text on the lines that match the regex.

Comment: Thank all of you for your comments, and I've re-edit the problem, please refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem by scripting. And I pushed the code to github in case any others need it.
Please refer to [EnhancedG.vim](https://github.com/TroyDanielFZ/Vim-Script).
For requirements:

1. The current contains `[a-z]`;
2. 3 lines after contains `\d`;
3. 2 lines before contains `example`;
4. Perform appending `Some text` to the line before;
   will be a simple ex-command:

```
:G/[a-z]/+3/\d/-2/example/norm ASome text
```

---

And another example:
For requirements:

1. The current contains `to delete`;
2. The next line does not matches `^$`;
3. Delete the current line;

would simple be:

```
:G/to delete/+!/^$/d
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to append text at the end of each matched first line, but not with `:subst` command.

`:global` with `:normal` will help you achieve it:

```
:g/^This.*\ze\n.*red/normal Asome text to be appended
```

If you want to append to second line, just add "j" like this:

```
:g/^This.*\ze\n.*red/normal jAsome text to be appended
```

Comment: Thanks for help and the problem is re-editted for a more clarifying explanation, please refer to the renewed statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `\v` which means "very magic search" so you can use regex groups like this:

```
/\v(red|blue|purple)
```

Then your regex matches each one of the above options you want. It would be better to show us the desired output, so we could understand better what you want as a result.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what you mean isn't what I'm seeking to.